# OOP -- defining an interface method with a certain intent

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm developing a computational framework to run some calculations on the given data-sets. 
It runs the data-set across a few algorithms, say `Calculator`-s, and picks the best outcome.

Each `Calculator` (there are 3 now) runs on *“basic-input”* and *“specific-input”. “Basic-input”* here is the same for all `Calculator`-s: the data-set in a certain form and a set of tuning params to tell the client preferences. In addition, each `Calculator` runs on “*specific-input*”: 2 or 3 parameters to tell the assumed restrictions to it. (The `Calculator`-s are solving an NP-hard problem-- the “*specific-input”* are tuning each Calculator on these restrictions and vary in type & number by the `Calculator`.)

A `Calculator` in the system is a type that implements a `Calculator` interface – that's how the system recognizes them. The `Calculator` interface has a `runCalculator()` method – the handle to invoke it.

Currently, the signature of `runCalculator()` is as follows:

```
Result runCalculator(Object...settings) ;
```

`Result` here is a type that defines the ultimate result they all produce.

In the framework, I'm currently passing the “*basic-input”* params to constructor of each `Calculator`, and “*specific-input”* params to `runCalculator()` of each of them. So – they all are instantiated on the same set of arguments, then run on the specific ones they each take.

My colleague argues that

```
Object...settings
```

in the definition of `runCalculator()` in the interface is too vague – it should be precise, define and take the “*basic-input”* for one, then take the rest of it as precisely as possible.

My counter-argument is: `runCalculator()` in the interface is a handle – telling the client the method to invoke the `Calculator` to deliver the result. It can not be specific with all the params, cause the “*specific-input”* are different for each `Calculator` implementing it. I can change it to also take the “*basic-input”* -- to be something like:

```
Result runCalculator(DataSet dataSet, Integer theCode, Object...settings) ;
```

and leave each constructor bare. This would instantiate each `Calculator` with nothing on, then leave all the work to `runCalculator()`. The constructors now are setting it up for the basics before `runCalculator()` gets in with the calculations.

We're running Java 7. If it were Java 8, i could make `runCalculator()` a static method, then take from there – `runCalculator()` would invoke the constructor, then the real-deal and this would tidy it up to both our “pleasure”.

I'm looking for opinions on this – how right/wrong are me and my colleague each?

**Note – 1**: This may look like a matter of **Strategy Pattern**, but it isn't. The client still has to pass the “specific-input” to a Calculator – the Q is how-well-defined to pass them.

**Note-2**: May also look like the **Builder Pattern** but isn't for the same reason.

TIA.

//================================

EDIT:

The `Calculator`-s can run on "*basic-input"* each. "*specific-input*" are settings when the client wants to feed them in and surpass the default settings.

EDIT-2:

**Interface is to make Calculator-s known to client without the client having to know which calculator, taking which "specific-input".**

Comment: "_I'm looking for opinions on this_" You might want to remove this part before people vote to close for being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Why do you need an interface at all?  It sounds like the command line arguments specify which class should be called.  Frankly, this doesn't really sound like a use for an interface at all.  You should write code which uses your interface and if you cannot do that in a general way, then interfaces probably aren't the correct construct.

Comment: I agree with @Jared ... ive read this post 4 times and still cant figure out how the "calculators" differ ... your implementation depends on "input" ? thats just wrong.Implementation should depend on what the calculator does...

Comment: Maybe you can use generics to get ride of `Object...settings`

Comment: @JorgeCampos - how do generics help? params are Integer & Double, some take 2 params some take 3.

Comment: It was already answred by @Saposhiente ... At least is the same I was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly, the problem is that your interface specifies a runCalculator method, but you do not know what objects exactly the calculator will require to run. This sounds like an appropriate situation to use generics:

```
public interface Calculator<SETTINGS> {
    Result runCalculator(SETTINGS settings);
    ...
}
```

This allows each Calculator class to define what type of object it is looking for. Subclasses that require multiple parameters can define a custom class to contain the parameters they need.

```
public class FooCalculator implements Calculator<FooCalculator.Settings> {
    ...
    public static class Settings {
        public final int param1;
        public final double param2;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: looks better, although not different than Objects...settings

Comment: @Roam It's better than Objects... because each class is guaranteed to receive the correct type of Object for each parameter.